# connection Birt Report with Google Sql Cloud

Tags: reporting, google-cloud-sql

i am creating a reporting :-

Development of a reporting software with Google SQL Cloud as directed by us. Google SQL Cloud needs to be configured first.

do you have any suggestion for it. i am new in it . but i have knowledge about birt eclipse reporting.  can i use birt eclipse reporting for it.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for connecting reporting tools to Cloud SQL.  I don't know the specifics of Birt, but these instructions should point you in the right direction.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin_tools

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  But when i am creating google cloud sql instance after creating account in google cloud. i have problem in creating instance by "Authorized applications". could you tell me about "Authorized applications". and i can created my google instance.

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes:

Step 1 - Download Connector J - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Step 2 - In Eclipse, Data Explorer > Data Sources (right click) > New Data Source > JDBC Data Source (& name your source) > Next..

Step 3 - Click "Manage Drivers..." before filling out the form > Add.. > Choose the .JAR extracted from Step 1

Step 4 - Choose "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (v5.1)", URL = jdbc:mysql://:/, User Name: root, Password: your password, JNDI blank

Step 5 - Test the connection. Check to ensure your DB allows unsecure connections and the IP you are connecting from is allowed in the console.